\begin{listing} environment taking full page width when used inside of \begin{itemize} environment
I am using \begin{listing} environment inside of \begin{itemize} environment. But the listing output is taking full page width instead of the itemize environment width.
Here is the complete example:
Code:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{minted}
\definecolor{light-gray}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.95}
 \setminted{bgcolor=light-gray} 

\begin{document}

\section{example}

Example of itemize list inside enumrate list:

\begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*)]
    \item enumrated item 1
\begin{itemize}
  \item   itemeize item number 1. each itemize item contains a code. the code for this iteize is shown in listing \ref{lst:1}.
    \begin{listing}[h]
    \centering
     \caption{Example of True  Dependency}
    \label{lst:1}
    \vspace{-.5\baselineskip}
    \begin{minted}{C}
        Statement i: a = 5
        Statement j: b = a + 3
    \end{minted}
   
 \vspace{-.5\baselineskip}
\end{listing} 
\end{itemize}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}

the output of the above code is:

Kindly suggest how can the listing size set to be content inside the width of itemize side. Thank you for your advise.

Welcome to tex.sx.

listing is a float like table or figure as such it goes to some lengths not to inherit the fonts and linewidth at the point it is saved as it is a document insert that will be re-inserted (perhaps at the same place perhaps elsewhere) If you want a code display that is part of the list just use minted directly not wrapped in a listing.

also you should provide a real example, there are two common packages for code listing, listings and minted  but you show one fragment loading listings but not showing any use and one fragment showing minted being used which you do not show being loaded.

@DavidCarlisle i have edited the question and give the complete code with o/p image. I have also tried the linewidth parameter inside the \lstset{ }. but it didn't change the size of the listing code.

you could remove \usepackage{listings} as you are not using that package.
